# Php работа с PayPal

Tags: php, paypal

Как получить ответ об успешной транзакции? Пишу на `Codigniter` интернет-магазин, нашел простую библиотеку для совершения платежей. Все вроде как надо работает, но надо получать какой то статус об успешной транзакции, чтобы потом высылать на е-маил письмо.

Comment: Документацию по используемой библиотеке или [PayPal REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-payments-overview/) не смотрели?

Comment: Не совсем разобрался в ней!

Comment: А какую библиотеку используете?

Comment: https://github.com/jersonandyworks/Paypal-Library-by-RomyBlack

Выбрал ее так как показалась простой и понятной, все что нужно было реализовать получилось,только вот момент с получением ответа не понятен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PayPal` использует достаточно распространенную технологию - IPN ([Instant Payment Notification](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)). Она позволяет информировать мерчантов (продавцов) о статусе транзакции. Для этого `PayPal` должен знать адрес обработчика в интернет магазине, то есть куда отсылать эту информацию.

Никогда не использовал `Codigniter`, но в библиотеке, которую Вы скинули, в коде есть комментарий:

```
$config['notify_url'] = 'process_payment.php'; //IPN Post

/**
 * The notify url is where paypal will POST the information of the payment 
 * so you can save that POST directly into your DB and analize as you want.
 */
```

То есть в этом параметре конфига необходимо указать адрес обработчика.

Comment: Хорошо обработчик принял параметры допустим,занес в базу статус платежа,если он не успешный допустим,когда в след раз сервер пошлет опять данные?

Comment: @quaresma89, переформулируй вопрос, пожалуйста. Ничего не понял.

Comment: Ну вот смотрите я оплачиваю заказ да,IPN посылает при этом ответ в обработчик,может же быть такое что платеж еще не обработался?То есть IPN как я понял должен посылать мне запрос до тех пор пока платеж не будет успешынм я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @quaresma89, да, сначала обрабатывается транзакция, а уже потом происходит колбек со статусом транзакции